# componentDidMount() fetch for local data

Tags: json, reactjs

I'm trying to test a React component with a JSON file that I have stored in a directory in my project.

I'm not sure if I'm going about this the right way:

```
    constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      videoPath: video,
      data: null
    }
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    fetch('../../data/jsonfile.json')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({data}));

  }
```

I get an error that says: 
`Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0`

The JSON file starts off:

```
{
    "0":{
        "coords":[
            [
                645.0,
                353.0,
                0.9010798558592796,
                0.0,
                0.0
            ],
```

So there shouldn be a `<` in there at all.  But when I inspect sources in Chrome jsonfile.json looks just like an HTML file.  I'm using `create-react-app`

Comment: Thanks I’m running out now but when I get back I will look at it and if it is I will delete this.

Comment: Your server is probably serving an error page because the json file was not found. The error page is HTML, which always starts with `<`, hence the javascript error "unexpected token". Make sure the path to the json file in your fetch statement is correct.